# Weird bug from textview in a listview while paginating

Tags: listview, pagination, textview, sax

I have a problem. I am currently doing an app that allows the user to paginate from an online xml source using SAX. I display the results in a listview. However when I paginate from one page to the other, the textviews would sometimes kinda stretch out beyond the screen or squeezed into a small area.
Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! It seems that in my xml file where I have my listview, I was also using TableLayout to add in a few buttons above my listview. I need to add this into my tablelayout properties.

> android:stretchcolumns="*"